# Maximal subgroups of almost simple classical groups which are almost simple

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite almost simple group with socle $S$ classical and $M$ be a maximal subgroup of $G$ not containing $S$. I'm interested in the pairs $(G,M)$ such that $M$ is almost simple.

If $M$ is almost simple, then so is $M\cap S$. I want to know the converse: given pair $(S,N)$ such that $N$ is almost simple, how to determine the pair $(G,M)$ such that $M$ is almost simple? For example, given $(S,N)=(Sp_{2m}(q),SO_{2m}(q))$ where $m\ge2$ and $q$ is even, is it true that for any maximal subgroup $M$ of $G$ such that $M\cap S=N$, $M$ is almost simple?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $N$ is of geometric type, then you can find the answer in the book by Kleidman and Liebeck. In your example, $N$ is in Aschbacher Class $\mathcal{C}_8$, and the answer to your question is yes, because the only automorphisms of $S$ are field automorphisms, which also act as field automorphisms of $N$.

If $N$ is not of geometric type, then it is in Aschbacher class $\mathcal{S}$, and it is always true that, for any associated pair $(G,M)$, $M$ is almost simple. That follows from the definition of Class $\mathcal{S}$, which excludes any groups that would be centralized by outer automorphisms of $S$.

Comment: In my example, $S$ has no diagonal automorphisms, but it has graph automorphism of order $2$ when $m=2$. Then is the answer still yes? BTW, I wonder if you would kindly point out which part of Kleidman and Liebeck's book I should read?